# E/flutter ( 3719): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Could not launch https://www.google.gr/?hl=el

Tags: flutter, url-launcher

I have a error when I click the `FloatingActionButton`. Can you help me please?
When I press the button from my physical device my program stops and I must resume it from debug tools.
This is my code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    final appbar = appbarBuilder();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appbar,
      body: body,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        onPressed: () async {
          const url = 'https://www.google.gr/?hl=el';
          if (await canLaunch(url)) {
            await launch(url);
          } else {
            throw 'Could not launch $url';
          }
        },
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/instagram.png',
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your device cannot launch the url, and it throws an exception as mentioned in the code "Throw"

Comment: Yeah, I know that but I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

You should restore your emulator..I have face this problem ,i just restore this emeulator